# PHP Web site cannot run properly on IIS

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, rewrite

We run a main site and want to run a second site under /tesmer folder. On the demo site it works perfectly. When I upload it on a Windows server just /tesmer/ displayed correctly. Any subpages likes /tesmer/smmm-sinav-islemleri has got 404 error.

We use Url rewrite and it seems like url rewrite is faulty under IIS.

Working page under development site:
http://demo.dijitall.net/izsm/tesmer/smmm-sinav-islemleri

Non-working page on IIS / Windows Server 2016
http://yeni.izsmmmo.org.tr/tesmer/smmm-sinav-islemleri

Below is the web.config file in /tesmer folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 10">
                    <match url="^([0-9a-zA-Z-_/]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?par={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 20" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^resimmap.xml$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="resimmap.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What would be the solution? Correct url write rule or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I've added that rule:

```
<rule name="tesmer22" stopProcessing="true">

  <match url="^tesmer/([0-9a-zA-Z-_/]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    </conditions>

  <action type="Rewrite" url="tesmer\index.php?par={R:1}" />        

</rule>
```